# Time complexity analysis of assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86, big-o, time-complexity

**EDIT:**
What time complexity has algorithm implemented in this assembly ?

```
    .file   "a.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "%d\n"
.LC1:
    .string "%d"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $32, %esp
    cmpl    $1, 8(%ebp)
    jg  .L2
    movl    $.LC0, %eax
    movl    $-1, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    printf
    jmp .L8
.L2:
    movl    $.LC1, %edx
    movl    12(%ebp), %eax
    addl    $4, %eax
    movl    (%eax), %eax
    leal    24(%esp), %ecx
    movl    %ecx, 8(%esp)
    movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    __isoc99_sscanf
    testl   %eax, %eax
    jne .L4
    movl    $.LC0, %eax
    movl    $-2, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    printf
    jmp .L8
.L4:
    movl    24(%esp), %eax
    testl   %eax, %eax
    jns .L5
    movl    $.LC0, %eax
    movl    $-3, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    printf
    jmp .L8
.L5:
    movl    $0, 28(%esp)
    jmp .L6
.L7:
    addl    $1, 28(%esp)
.L6:
    movl    24(%esp), %eax
    cmpl    %eax, 28(%esp)
    jl  .L7
    movl    $.LC0, %eax
    movl    28(%esp), %edx
    movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    printf
.L8:
    leave
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you understand what time complexity means?

Comment: Speculatively added the [homework] tag.

Comment: No, it's not homework, it's just interesting puzzle to ASM and CS gurus...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only a small section of your assembly where control flows in a way other than straight-ahead execution or forward jumps (or calls to `printf` or `sscanf` with a format string of `"%d"`).  Since those sections of the code are only executed once, they have complexity O(1).

So the only interesting complexity is in the place where a backwards jump is possible:

```
.L5: movl    $0,    28(%esp)
     jmp     .L6
.L7: addl    $1,    28(%esp)
.L6: movl 24(%esp),    %eax
     cmpl    %eax,  28(%esp)
     jl      .L7
```

This is just a basic for loop; in C it would look like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i);
```

*An aside: this brings up a danger of using "abstract pseudocode" to talk about the complexity of assembly; this loop does nothing so the abstract pseudocode equivalent, in some sense, is empty and has complexity O(1).  The actual code, however, has complexity O(n).*

So this loop takes O(n) time, where n is the value of the input to the program as an integer.  Since the rest of the program takes O(1) time, the program as a whole runs in O(n).

Answer (score 2):

Time-complexity is about algorithm, not implementations, therefore you have to "reverse-engineer" it back.

You have to do it with every language, assembly being just one of those.

The fact that understanding an algorithm expressed with - say - java is easier than doing it with ASM doesn't change the state of affairs.

*Edit: parts of this answer is just copied from my comments below.*

Comment: First you'd need to "reverse engineer" the x86 code back to a higher level abstraction, e.g. pseudo code, then do the analysis on that.

Comment: @0x69: you have to understand what the algorithm is with every language, assembly being one of those. The fact that understanding the algorithm with - say - java is easier doesn't change the state of affairs.

Comment: There's no need to "reverse engineer" anything.  Assembly is a perfectly fine unambiguous description language for an algorithm, no different from pseudocode.  You can perform exactly the same analysis on the raw assembly source to determine the time or space complexity.

Comment: @Stephen: it's "reverse engineer", not reverse engineer. The point is that complexity analysis deals with the essential structure of an algorithm, so you need to understand it in an abstract way. ASM is of course very, very, very precise, so you need to abstract a lot of things, which is an activity that can be characterized as "reverse engineer".

Comment: @akappa: You need to *understand* it, not *abstract* it.  Time complexity is a property of the abstract algorithm, but it is not actually necessary to operate at that level of abstraction.  Some people may find it easier, however.

Comment: tr.v. (b-strkt) ab·stract·ed, ab·stract·ing, ab·stracts
1. To take away; remove. So yes, you *need* to abstract away irrelevant details, like the way you layout your structures in memory or the precise registers allocated to some counters to understand if your algorithm is linear or not.

Comment: But what is irrelevant is in the eye of the beholder. If your guru level is high enough, you don't need to reverse engineer asm, you will eating it for breakfast. But I won't argue that for most people analyzing an abstract high level algorithm is easier than to analyze the whole thing including all gory details. But you risk always leaving out important details you don't recognize as important and so your analysis may become flawed. Anyway, there exists no general algorithm to prove that the run time of an algorithm is finite,and that can be proven - but unfortunately thereisnotenoughroomleft